# Why @GetMapping & @PostMapping throw error for same URI?

Tags: spring, spring-restcontroller

> Option-1: Worke fine

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "myuri/" ,method = RequestMethod.GET)
 MyResponse myMethod1(@RequestBody MyRequest myRequest) {
   // Code
 }

@RequestMapping(value = "myuri/" ,method = RequestMethod.POST)
 MyResponse myMethod2(@RequestBody MyRequest myRequest) {
   // Code
 }
```

> Option-2: Doesn't work

```java
@GetMapping
@RequestMapping(value = "myuri/" )
MyResponse myMethod1(@RequestBody MyRequest myRequest) {

    return null;
}

@PostMapping
@RequestMapping(value = "myuri/")
MyResponse myMethod2(@RequestBody MyRequest myRequest) {
    return null;
}
```

> Why option-2 throws an exception
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping.

```java
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'myRestController' method 
com.a.b.c.service.model.MyResponse com.a.b.my.service.rest.myRestController.myMethod2(com.a.b.c.service.model.MyRequest)
to { /my/myuri/}: There is already 'myRestController' bean method
com.a.b.c.service.model.MyResponse com.a.b.my.service.rest.myRestController.myMethod1(com.a.b.c.service.model.MyRequest) mapped.
```

Comment: Because the `@GetMapping` doesn't limit the `@RequestMapping`. Instead you should use `@GetMapping("myuri/")` .

Comment: Ahh!!! That's what I was missing. So I can say its shortcut for @RequestMapping(value = "myuri/" ,method = RequestMethod.GET). Thanks.

Comment: That is exactly what it is. If you check the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/GetMapping.html) you see itself to be annotated with `@RequestMapping(method=GET)`. It is a convenience annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first sample maps 2 methods to a single URL with different post methods.

1. `@RequestMapping(value = "myuri/" ,method = RequestMethod.GET)` this will lead to a mapping for a GET request on `myuri` to go the `myMethod1`.
2. `@RequestMapping(value = "myuri/" ,method = RequestMethod.POST)` this will lead to a mapping for a POST request on `myuri` to go the `myMethod2`.

Your second sample maps 2 methods to 2 URLs with both different and same methods.

1. `@RequestMapping(value = "myuri/")` this will lead to a mapping for a **ANY** request on `myuri` to go the `myMethod1`.
2. `@GetMapping` this will lead to a GET request on `/` to go to the `myMethod1`.
3. `@RequestMapping(value = "myuri/")` this will lead to a mapping for a **ANY** request on `myuri` to go the `myMethod2`.
4. `@PostMapping` this will lead to a POST request on `/` to go to the `myMethod1`.

As 1 and 3 are the same mapping going to different methods Spring cannot differentiate and throws an error.

This probably comes from the fact that you misunderstand the [`@GetMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/GetMapping.html) and [`@PostMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PostMapping.html) annotations and how to use them. The mappings are respectivily a shortcut for `@RequestMapping(method=GET)` and `@RequestMapping(method=POST)`. Saving you same space in your definition and they are quite clear.

So instead of

```
@GetMapping
@RequestMapping(value = "myuri/" )
```

You should just write `@GetMapping("myuri/")` to achieve what you want. As after detection this translates to a mapping for a GET request on `myuri` to go the given method.

Comment: Does in "this will lead to a mapping for a GET request on myuri to go the myMethod2." should not be "POST"?

Comment: Whoops, sloppy paste :). fixed.